# Status = success dispite my images are not full loaded from API in react-query3

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I'm learning how to use react-query by fetching images from unsplash API.

I want to set a spinner while my images are fetching but the status is set to success even before my images are fully loaded on the page (i've checked with a console.log(status))

This is what I have:

App.js

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "react-query";
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from "react-query/devtools";
import GetImages from "./components/GetImages";
import NavBar from "./components/NavBar";
import PostImage from "./components/PostImage";

function App() {
  const queryClient = new QueryClient();
  const [page, setPage] = useState("get");

  return (
    <>
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        <div className="App">
          <NavBar setPage={setPage} />
          <div>{page === "get" ? <GetImages /> : <PostImage />}</div>
        </div>
        <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false} />
      </QueryClientProvider>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

GetImages.js

```js
import React from "react";
import { useQuery } from "react-query";
import Image from "./Image";
import Spinner from "react-bootstrap/Spinner";

const fetchImage = async () => {
  let config = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Client-ID ID",
    },
    mode: "cors",
    cache: "default",
  };
  const res = await fetch("https://api.unsplash.com/photos", config);
  return res.json();
};

const GetImages = () => {
  const { data, status } = useQuery("images", fetchImage);

  return (
    <div>
      {status === "loading" && (
        <Spinner animation="border" role="status">
          <span className="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
        </Spinner>
      )}

      {status === "error" && <div>Error</div>}

      {status === "success" && data.map((image) => <Image key={image.id} image={image} />)}
    </div>
  );
};

export default GetImages;
```

Image.js

```js
const Image = ({ image }) => {
  return (
    <div className="card">
      <img src={image.urls.raw} alt={image.alt_description} style={{ width: 100, height: "auto" }} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Image;
```

I don't know what the best way to achieve what I need. Basically I want only one spinner that appear on the middle of the page and display my divs once all images are fully loaded like this the user won't see the images loading on its page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are creating a `new QueryClient` *inside* your `App` - so every time it re-renders, for example, because you call `setPage`, you will get a new QueryClient, which also means a new Cache.

The QueryClient must be stable, either created outside of App, or by using a constant like:

```
const queryClient = useState(() => new QueryClient())[0]
```

Comment: Thanks to you, so I managed to make it (I posted the answer). Could you just let me know what does mean [0] ? What about if I had few api call on the same page ? (sorry I'm learning react-query since today)

Comment: useState returns an array with two elements so we take the first element from it with [0]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks the answer below. I managed to make it like this:

App.js

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "react-query";
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from "react-query/devtools";
import GetImages from "./components/GetImages";
import NavBar from "./components/NavBar";
import PostImage from "./components/PostImage";

function App() {
  const queryClient = useState(() => new QueryClient())[0];
  const [page, setPage] = useState("get");

  return (
    <>
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        <div className="App">
          <NavBar setPage={setPage} />
          <div>{page === "get" ? <GetImages /> : <PostImage />}</div>
        </div>
        <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false} />
      </QueryClientProvider>
    </>
  );
}
```

GetImages.js

```js
import React from "react";
import { useQuery } from "react-query";
import Image from "./Image";

const fetchImage = async () => {
  let config = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Client-ID ID    },
    mode: "cors",
    cache: "default",
  };
  const res = await fetch("https://api.unsplash.com/photos", config);
  return res.json();
};

const GetImages = () => {
  const { data, status } = useQuery("images", fetchImage);

  return (
    <div>
      {status === "error" && <div>Error</div>}

      {status === "success" && data.map((image) => <Image key={image.id} image={image} />)}
    </div>
  );
};

export default GetImages;
```

Images.js

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import Spinner from "react-bootstrap/Spinner";

const Image = ({ image }) => {
  const [load, setLoad] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="card">
      <img
        src={image.urls.raw}
        alt={image.alt_description}
        style={load ? { width: 100, height: "auto" } : { display: "none" }}
        onLoad={() => setLoad(true)}
      />
      {!load && (
        <>
          <Spinner animation="border" role="status">
            <span className="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
          </Spinner>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Image;
```